# Binary file can't be used more than once ?

Tags: c++, file-handling

Heres my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct a
{
    int x;
    int b;
};

int main ()
{

ifstream rfile("test.bin", ios::binary);
a ob;

//Reading from the file for the first time works fine.
rfile.read((char*)&ob, sizeof(ob));
while (rfile) 
{
    cout<<ob.x<<endl;
    rfile.read((char*)&ob, sizeof(ob));
}
rfile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

cout<<"G:"<<rfile.tellg()<<endl; //Outputs -1
rfile.read((char*)&ob, sizeof(ob));
while (rfile) 
{
    cout<<ob.x<<endl;
    rfile.read((char*)&ob, sizeof(ob));
}


return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
3
1
G:-1
```

As in the first loop works and second loop dosent work since the position of the pointer is at -1 even after using seekg(). Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ifstream is in invalid state after first while loop, you need to reset stream state flags prior to any further operations on the stream.

```
    rfile.read((char*)&ob, sizeof(ob));
}
rfile.clear();
rfile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

instead of

```
    rfile.read((char*)&ob, sizeof(ob));
}
rfile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because in C++98, The `seekg()` behaves differently from C++11. In C++98, if the `eofbit` flag is set before the call, the function fails (sets failbit and returns). you can check the return value to verify that.

In C++11, this function clears the `eofbit` if set before the call.